# Regex VB.net Should I Group?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have wrote the following code to cut down the information I have in each line

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, "(a\/users\/\d*).*\(.*", "$1")
```

The string starts as this:

> /a/users/15/badges?params%5Bnotifications%5D%5Bcount%5D=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 143 "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"

Im trying to get to

> /a/users/15/ (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"

Am I going far wrong? If anyone can assist I would be grateful.

---

When i try this:

s = Regex.Replace(s, "(a/users/\d*).*(\Blackberry.*).*", "$1 $2")'

To sort the following line

/a/users/80021/messages.json?params[page]=1&params[per_page]=10&params[set_actions]=true HTTP/1.1" 200 13063 "BlackBerry9320/7.1.0.398 Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/603 tibbr/3.6.6.1" 1/1574070

It does not work it doesnt seem to recognise the / after the /a/users/80021

Thanks again for your help, im learning so much its great.

i will have a a look at HttpUtility as well

Comment: That string is a query string -- why not use a simple query string parser, such as `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`?

Comment: On second look, you have a URL and a user-agent string concatenated. My above comment is probably not as useful now that I see that. Are you trying to parse IIS logs or something?

Comment: If that line comes from a log file, it is likely that the parts are separated by tab characters. In which case you could simplify the problem by using String.Split on it and then apply a regex to the relevant parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't escape the slashes and match the third group as well:

```
(a/users/\d*/).\((.*)\).*
```

You also need to end the regex with `.*` to make sure the remaining characters are removed.

Or:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, "(a/users/\d*/).*(\(.*\)).*", "$1 $2")
```

[**DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Mywt0).

But as @Cory argues: one better uses library implemented algoritms like `HttpUtility` since these are designed following all specifications and less likely to contain bugs.

**EDIT**: About your second regex, there is an error in:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, "(a\/users\/\d*).*(\Blackberry\.*).*","$1 $2")
```

You don't escape the brackets, but `B` and `.`, the correct regex is probably:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, "(a\/users\/\d*/).*(Blackberry.*).*","$1 $2")
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help i have been playing for a couple of days now and the one you did worked but when i ammend it for a different line it cant get it to work

Comment: When i try this:
 
's = Regex.Replace(s, "(a\/users\/\d*).*(\Blackberry\.*).*", "$1 $2")'

To sort the following line 

/a/users/80021/messages.json?params[page]=1&params[per_page]=10&params[set_actions]=true HTTP/1.1" 200 13063 "BlackBerry9320/7.1.0.398 Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/603 tibbr/3.6.6.1" 1/1574070

It does not work it doesnt seem to recognise the / after the /a/users/80021

Thanks again for your help, im learning so much its great.

i will have a a look at HttpUtility as well

Comment: Yes yes yes, thank you thank you, it works like a charm,  so why dont i need the \ with Blackberry then?

Comment: @vbvirg20: `\B` and `\b` are interpreted as [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) you only need to interpret a `b` or `B`.

Comment: Ok i have been trying and trying so for example if is use

Comment: Ok i have been trying and trying so for example if is use   Regex.Replace(s, "(a/users/\d*/).*(Mozilla.*).*", "$1 $2")     expecting the code will end up keeping a/users/12345/ then delete to Mozilla it doesnt it just removes the line, when i check the code in expresso it says its is correct but when i run in VB.net it just deletes the line.  example of the line i would run it across is as below:-

Comment: /a/users/49970/badges?params%5Bset_actions%5D=true&params%5Bmessages_since%5D=142001239333302&params%5Bsubscription_requests%5D%5Buser_id%5D=49970&params%5Bnotifications%5D%5Bstatus%5D=unread&params%5Bnotifications%5D%5Bcount%5D=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 147 "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)" 0/75549